# Fonts imported in a css file not loading when invoked from Service

Tags: angular

Why I am trying to do so? Ans: I am trying to get Tenant specific styling in `Angular v13`.

**Theme Loading Block** :

```
    const headEl = this.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    const newLinkEl = this.document.createElement('link');
    newLinkEl.rel = 'stylesheet';
    newLinkEl.href = 'tenant-a.css'
    headEl.appendChild(newLinkEl);
```

**tenant-a.css** :

```
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Pilat Wide';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-display: auto;
      src: url('../../assets/fonts/pilatwide/PilatWide-Regular-woff2.woff2') format('woff2');
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Pilat Bold';
      font-style: bold;
      font-weight: 600;
      font-display: auto;
      src: url('../../assets/fonts/pilatwide/PilatWide-Bold-woff2.woff2') format('woff2');
    }
```

When I directly invoke **Theme Loading Block** code in app.component.ts then in the network tab of browser I can see `tenant-a.css` and fonts getting loaded so the page text are also transforming with the new font. But when I create another theme service, created a method `loadTheme()`, used the same Theme Loading Block code and invoked that method from app.component.ts then in network tab I only see `tenant-a.css` is getting loaded but not the fonts.

**ThemeService.ts** :

```
public loadTheme() : void {
   const headEl = this.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    const newLinkEl = this.document.createElement('link');
    newLinkEl.rel = 'stylesheet';
    newLinkEl.href = 'tenant-a.css'
    headEl.appendChild(newLinkEl);
  }
```

**app.component.ts** :

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.themeService.loadTheme();
  }
```

I have not pasted all the code like in `angular.json` I have already added the styles with inject false.

If I invoke the `tenant-a.css` directly from app.component.ts it works fine as mentioned earlier but I am using the service for a more scalable approach.

I don't want to load the fonts in global css as I have 30 tenants and their fonts are different from one another so unnecessarily I don't want to load all the fonts.

In service I tried to apply a delay, but still its not working.

Comment: For testing purposes load a font from a web url instead of from your local folder. Maybe the relative path is incorrect in the service context

Comment: Thanks @Benny! I tried that it didn't work. Any way the relative path is from the tenant-a.css file.

Answer (score 2):

```
     @HostBinding('class') get hostClasses() {
        return this.themeService.getTheme();
      }
```

It was needed to add in app.component.ts